# SQL Syntax errors in VS Code in local vs remote host

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code, mariadb

I'm trying to containerize an app so I'm trying to write an init file for a MariaDB database for an existing database that exists on a remote server. I'm using VS Code to connect to the remote server and the .sql file with the contents of the dump has no errors, but when I try and copy it to a different workspace on my local computer, I get many syntax errors.

Examples of the syntax errors:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `accounts`;
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `table_number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `account_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL, 
  `account_name` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`table_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=261 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

```
Incorrect syntax near '`'. Expecting '(', or SELECT. 

Incorrect syntax near '11'. Expecting '(', or SELECT.
```

The error about the ` character is present before "accounts" and before both instances of "table_number" but not before "account_id" and "account_name". Every number in the CREATE has the incorrect syntax warning. I've tried retyping rather than copy and pasting to see if there's hidden characters responsible for these issues, but no luck.

Is this an OS issue? The remote server is a CentOS machine and my local is macOS Catalina. A setting in VS Code I need to specify or change?

Comment: I'd guess you are trying to run these statements on Microsoft SQL Server, or Microsoft Access, not MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: @BillKarwin Do you know how I might be able to check and/or change that?

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION;` will work on both Microsoft and MySQL/MariaDB. What does it say?

Comment: Remote: 10.1.46-MariaDB and Local terminal: 10.5.5-MariaDB Homebrew

Comment: I downloaded MariaDB 10.5 and tested your CREATE TABLE. It works with no error. I have no idea what the problem is. Perhaps it's something VS Code is doing to pre-validate the SQL DDL. I don't use VS Code, so I can't suggest anything. But I'd search the VS Code documentation to see if there is any mention of SQL validation. Perhaps you need to configure your VS Code to understand the MySQL/MariaDB brand of syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove all the backticks `, the validation errors should go away.

I think the problem is VS is expecting MS SQL syntax.

The backticks are used in MySQL to delimit names which might include silly things like spaces or reserved words. If you don't have any conflicts like that, you can remove all the backticks. The export tools usually include them by default when dumping the schemas, but you can probably configure it to suppress them to reduce this pain.

However the backticks aren't the only difference, so you may still get other incompatibilities flagged (e.g. I also see errors like this on  `REPLACE INTO` and `NOW()`).

I'm looking for a way to tell VS "this is mysql!" but haven't found it yet.